# SQLAlchemy ignoring None when comparing date

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to get rows from specified date range, but when limiter is None (beg_date==None, fin_date==None) I want to ignore scope on one side.

For instance:
If beg_date=='2019-10-23' and fin_date==None I would like to get
rows from 2019-10-23 up to date.
How can I achieve that using SQLAlchemy?

Model:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    date = Column(Date)
```

Code:

```
beg_date = some_dict.get('beg_date')
fin_date = some_dict.get('fin_date')

session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.date.between(beg_date, find_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build your date condition with Python conditions on `start_date` and `end_date` before building your whole query:

```
if start_date and end_date:
    date_condition = MyModel.date.between(start_date, end_date)
elif start_date:
    date_condition = MyModel.date > start_date
elif end_date:
    date_condition = MyModel.date < end_date
else:
    date_condition = true()  # sqlalchemy.true()

session.query(MyModel).filter(date_condition)
```

I did not tested it but it should work with potential minor fixes.